# PovRay conversion

Tags: file-conversion, povray

According to my recollection, once an object or a scene was described in PovRay, there was no other output than the rendering generated.  In other words, once exported *into* *.pov, you were no longer able to convert it into an other 3D file format.

Hence I was very surprised to learn about [pov2mesh](http://graphics.cyborg5.com/2016/10/29/converting-pov-ray-shapes-to-triangle-mesh-for-3-d-printing/) that aims to generate a point cloud, thanks to [meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) eventually suitable for 3D printing.

As I have a number of scenes defined only as *.pov describing molecules (so, spheres and sticks) and colour encoded molecular surfaces from computation, I wonder if there were a way to convert / rewrite such a scene into a format like vrml 2.0, preserving both shape and colour of them.

Performing the computation again and saving the result straight ahead as vrml is not an option, as beside binary output understood by the software, the choice to save the results is either *.png, or *.pov.

Or is there a povray editor, that is able to understand a *.pov produced by other software, and offeres to export the scene in *.vrml (or a different 3D file format)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an editor that converts from .pov to .vrml, but both formats are text based. Since your pov file is only made out of sphere and cylinders you could convert it by hand, or write a simple program to do it for you. Here is a red sphere in Povray (http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.2/283/)

```
sphere{
    <0, 0, 0>, 1
    pigment{
        color rgb <1, 0, 0>
    }
}
```

I don't know much about vrml but this should be the equivalent (found here: https://www.siggraph.org/special-projects/com97/vrmlexample1.html)

```
Shape {
     appearance Appearance {
         material Material { 
             diffuseColor 1.0 0.0 0.0
             transparency 0.0
         }
     }
    geometry Sphere {
        radius 1.0
    }
}
```